# How to access byte[] data in .Net Web API Multipart Form Request

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, multipartform-data

I have a request that my Web is receiving - from looking at a wireshark I can see that the form contains two parts.

The first part is type `application/json` and is called `metadata` and the second part is `audio/wav` and is called `media_audio_wav`, and both have content-disposition set to `form-data`. I do not control the request coming in so I need to make it work with what I'm getting.

I have a controller method declared like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyControllerMethod([FromForm] MyModelClass jsonInput)
{   
    await _myClass.DoSomeBusinessLogic(jsonInput);
        
    return Ok();
}
```

In the above, `MyModelClass` is a class that the JSON part successfully binds to. What I want to figure out is how to get the `byte[]` field called `media_audio_wav`. I have tried adding a second `[FromForm]` parameter and that didn't seem to work. I have also tried simply declaring a field in my model class that is of type `byte[]` with the proper name and that didn't work either.

If I declare a field in my model class of type string, the .NET model binder will bind to it, but because the data is binary, when it is converted to the string the audio comes out corrupted since strings cannot represent binary data properly. Because of this, I need to get the raw binary without first turning it into a string. I can't use `IFormFile` because there is not filename specified on the binary data.

Comment: Have you looked at `HttpContext.Request.Form.Files`? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52350447/in-asp-net-core-how-can-i-get-the-multipart-form-data-from-the-body) might be of help.

Comment: Again, it's not uploaded as a file. It's binary data. I've tried accessing that property but there is nothing in it because it isn't included as a file.

Comment: What you might need to do is declare `public class MyModelClass { [FromForm(Name = "json_field_name")] public string Json { get; set; } [FromForm(Name = "media_audio_wav")] public byte[] Audio { get; set; } }` and then change your controller method to **not** have the `[FromForm]` annotation on the parameter.

Comment: I'll try that, but while searching I also found this question - it is unanswered, but if we answered it it would probably solve my problem. The reason I can't just use IFormFile is because there is no filename declared. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60157395/how-to-bind-a-multipart-form-data-file-without-filename-to-iformfile-in-asp-net

Comment: Can you share your code about you pass MyModelClass  to MyControllerMethod?Maybe you can do in the link `content.Add(fileContent, "File", "36KB.pdf");`Add a default name to it.Maybe you can try custom model binding.